# "User not found" Error when creating a child entity using ControllerB action, soon after an aspUser is created in controllerA

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

After the successful creation of an application user and the following line of code (in Register action in AccountController) :

```
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
```

I am trying to add a child object

```
var controller=DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<AnotherController>();
                controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(Request.RequestContext, controller);

            var res = controller.Create(
                new ChildEntity
                {
                    ApplicationUserId = user.Id,
                    IsAcative = true
                });
```

my create Method looks like this

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(ChildEntity entity)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        db.ChildEntity.Add(entity);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(entity);
}
```

My object is not created. the return value`res` contains the error "user not found" propertyName :  "ApplicationUserId"

Can anybody help me to understand what is going on?
ps : i have noticed that the User.Identity.GetUserId() return null !!! (may be fo some other reason, may be my problem is linked to this..)

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, the user principal is not populated until after the next page load. The sign-in process merely sets the auth cookie. That cookie needs to be sent back and the auth machinery needs to run (as part of the request pipeline), before you can get anything from `User`.

Second, what you're doing here is just absolutely wrong. If you want to reuse the user creation code, factor it out into another class that all your controllers can utilize. It's absolutely the wrong approach to try to new up a controller inside another action to call an action on that.

Comment: "factor it out into another class that all your controllers can utilize" I dont know what difference it make in just factoring out.. or I dont understant how to factor it out in the correct way.. can you give me an example please.. it would be so helpful. and what is the best way to call another controller action within the original one please?

Comment: @NishanthShaan MVC Controllers are not meant to be used the way you are trying to use it. Controllers are only HTTP endpoints, not reusable classes for internal consumption. Create another class that is not a controller and put `Create(ChildEntity entity)` method there. Use that class inside controllers.

Comment: Thanks, thats sounds cocnise and clear +1 . But this still paves way to another question.. I am wondering why even microsoft will create a class which permits to new up a controller inside another ?)